# magento 2 createPaypalExpressToken mutation GraphQL

Tags: magento2, paypal

I am using `createPaypalExpressToken` mutation for creating Paypal Express token.

```
Request :

mutation {
    createPaypalExpressToken(
        input: {
            cart_id: "9GXAiPDjB04H1OXOBndnrNIQwxQKFuWv"
            code: "paypal_express"
            express_button: true
            urls: {
                return_url: "paypal/action/return.html"
                cancel_url: "paypal/action/cancel.html"
            }
        }
    )
    {
        token
        paypal_urls{
            start
            edit
        }
    }
}   

Response :

{
  "data": {
    "createPaypalExpressToken": {
      "token": "<PayPal_Token>"
      "paypal_urls": {
        "start": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=<PayPal_Token>"
        "edit": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=continue&token=<PayPal_Token>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

API response response is getting fine. But when i open URL `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=continue&token=<PayPal_Token>`, I am getting `This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.` in paypal URL or Popup. URL working fine when generate from website.

Let me know if anyone have idea ?